# How do I go back to the previous page after tapping on a link in Apple Books?

Tags: ios, books

I'm in the Books app in iOS. I tap on a link to a different part in the same book (maybe to a reference in the back of book, maybe this was an accident). How do I figure out where in the book I was reading before that action, and how do I get back to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the book. They have to provide the necessary link.
Often for such as footnotes, the footnote number itself is the return link.

Personally, I always drop a bookmark before first venturing off into the unknown on any given book. I only stop doing that once I've firmly established they correctly wrote the return links.

Comment: It's a PDF. No return links. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading an epub and not a pdf, you get a return link in the top left corner if you first tap the center of the screen. You can also skip forward after skipping back (a redo after the undo) with a link in the top right corner.

Unfortunately the same UI is not available when reading pdfs.